# Do you need to generate you own nonce value for OpenID Grants client-side?

Tags: flask, authlib

I'm trying to authorize using the OIDC Implicit Grant from the client side. When generating the URI from the OAuth2Session authorization_url method, it doesn't include two required values: nonce and redirect_uri.

Are you supposed to generate your own nonce with JWT and carry over the redirect_uri from your registered Client?

I sideloaded a nonce and redirect_uri into the OAuth2Session but the authorization_url doesn't generate the uri with the nonce. It does however include the redirect_uri.

I lightly checked the authlib source and could not find a method to generate the nonce but only methods to verify it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass these parameters to `authorization_url`:

```
session.authorization_url(..., nonce='xxx')
```

You may find this piece of code useful: https://github.com/authlib/loginpass/blob/master/loginpass/_core.py#L130

---

I've updated the documentation for this use case:
https://docs.authlib.org/en/latest/client/oauth2.html#oauth-2-openid-connect

Comment: Is the response_type for authorization_url suppose to be 'token' or 'id_token'? If it set it as 'token' it gives me an InvalidGrant error and if it is set to 'id_token' it returns "RuntimeError: "exists_nonce" hook is not registered."

Comment: @TimeBigot what do you mean? How could it be possible. InvalidGrant and exists_nonce hook are used in the server side, not client side. How can a client usage trigger such a case?

Comment: Sorry I wasn't clear. When I visit the authorization url it gives me those errors. Was I not supposed to visit the url? Are you supposed to just pass the url to the fetch_access_token method? If I do that, I get a "Missing 'access token' error".

Comment: @TimeBigot I don't understand your question. Is it a server-side issue or a client side issue? If it is a server side issue, my guess is that you didn't implement the OpenID Connect grant right.

Comment: And Authlib is licensed under AGPL, you should open source your code. In that case I can figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: I would open source but it's a fresh Flask app with only Authlib code. I decided to simplify the auth with something else. I really appreciate your speedy replies. Thanks!

Comment: @TimeBigot I think this answered your current question. If you have further questions, please ask another one, and describe it clearly.